# Getting SharePoint Groups of User using HTTP Request in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, groups, flow

So currently I'm working on task, that will return all groups that user triggering the flow is member of.

I stuck on this:

[image]

My teammate gave me a hint, that this way is proper, but I need something more from inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a power automate flow like this:

[image]

Uri used in HTTP request action is:

```
_api/web/siteusers/getbyemail(<userEmail>)/groups
```

Replace `<userEmail>` with dynamic content from PowerApps (V2) trigger.

---

From Power apps, while running this flow, use formula like:

```
FlowName.Run(User().Email)
```

Replace `FlowName` with name of your flow.

Comment: One of the conditions this task is that the user have only to click the button. 
Users didn't have provide any informations like email or username. 

So this flow must be based on information about user before it triggers action

Comment: And please, if ofc you can, tell me what is the function of initialize variable in this flow.

Comment: User don't need to pass the user email manually. You can get the currently logged in users details using `User()` function in power apps. In my answer, we are passing currently logged in user's email (`User().Email`) to the flow when user runs the flow. You just need to add the formula (`FlowName.Run(User().Email)`) on `OnSelect` property of button. Replace `FlowName` with name of your flow.

Comment: You can ignore the initialize variable in this flow. This action I have used for my requirements.

Comment: Did you try it, is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but this task requires using GET method with `_api/web/GetUserByID` and then I need to get groups of user.

I have no idea what dynamic value I need to type after `GetUserByID`

URI that is needed to end this flow looks like this:
`hhtp://mysite/_api/web/GetUserById(" + userId + ")/Groups`

These are requirements are mandatory

Comment: You don't need `userId` in case you use this URI: `_api/web/siteusers/getbyemail(<userEmail>)/groups`. You only need the email address of user running the flow (which you are getting from Power apps).

Comment: So if I use `_api/web/siteusers/getbyemail(<userEmail>)/groups` and then in PowerApp 
when I create a button and give it `OnSelect` control `FlowName.Run(User().Email)` - the user won't have anything to input?

Comment: Yes correct. User don't need to input anything manually. currently logged in user's email will be sent to flow automatically using formula.

Comment: Okay, but should be there any next step to display this data in PowerApp screen? 

What should I use to display the result of flow in PowerApp? Label or Text field?

Comment: It depends on your requirements what you need to do with this data. If you want to show it in your app, you have to pass the output from flow to Power apps using "Respond to power apps or flow" action. Please [ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for this with detailed requirements what you need exactly.