# How to display result of HTTP Request as list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow, powerapp

So finally I know how to get users groups using HTTP request to SharePoint in [This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302888/getting-sharepoint-groups-of-user-using-http-request-in-power-automate/302889?noredirect=1#comment319561_302889).

Now I need to display these groups as list in Power App. (Or it can be organized text).

The raw output looks like this (rest of group outputs are similar):

[image]

My flow already looks like this:

[image]

Now I'm looking for a solution how to filter only a "Title" of all groups and display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the group names in a string variable & pass it to the power apps using "Respond to a PowerApp or flow" action. Configure your flow actions like this:

[image]

1. Formula used as input to Apply to each:

```
body('HTTP_request_to_SP_-_Get_User_Groups')['d']['results']
```

You need to replace this `'HTTP_request_to_SP_-_Get_User_Groups'` with your action name (with **_** instead of space in action name).

2. Formula used in Append to string variable action:

```
concat(item()['Title'], ';;')
```

2. Pass `userGroupNames` variable in "Respond to a PowerApp or flow" action.

You can enter these formula in Dynamic content section of respective flow actions.

---

Make below changes in Power Apps:

```
//Get SP groups of current user
Set(userGroupNamesString, FlowName.Run(User().Email).usergroupnames);

//Get collection of user group names
ForAll(Split(userGroupNamesString, ";;"), Collect(colUserGroupNames, Result));
```

You can use this collection `colUserGroupNames` to show group names in your app for example:

1. Add gallery control in your app & set `items` property of app to `colUserGroupNames`.
2. Add label control inside gallery & set it's `Text` property to: `ThisItem.Value`

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I'm still working on this solution, sorry for late response due the lack of time. 
Could you please be more clear in part when you write about "Make below changes in PowerApps"?
I guess you mean the `StartScreen` control in App element, is it right?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch user groups when app starts? If yes, you need to write above code in `OnStart` property of `App` element.

Comment: Well, I don't need to fetch user groups already on app start. Main goal was to fetch them after clicking button. So I'm not sure where I have to write `//Get SP groups of current user` formula

Comment: In that case, you have to write the complete formula in `OnSelect` property of the button control.

Comment: Sorry for no response. I will post a comment with actual results of this solution in a few days. Thanks for patience

Comment: were you able to follow the steps given in answer & get the user groups correctly in app?

Comment: I followed your steps and the result is acceptable. I met another problem about dynamic `Site Address` but I will create another post about it. For now it works propertly. Thanks for your patience and help.